Facing Missing authorization rules account
Not able to use ruleSet with updateAsUpdateAuthorityV2 where we are setting ruleSet and than updating authority in metadata.
const tx = await createProgrammableNft(umi, {
mint,
sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ROYALITY),
name: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PNFT_NAME,
symbol: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SYMBOL,
image: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_IMAGE_URL,
primarySaleHappened: true,
uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URI,
collection: {
  key: publicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COLLECTION_ADDRESS),
  verified: false,
},
creators: [
  {
    address: publicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECEIVER),
    share: 100,
    verified: false,
  },
],
ruleSet: publicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RULE_SET_ADDRESS),})
.add(
  transferSol(umi, {
    destination: publicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECEIVER),
    amount: sol(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NFT_PRICE),
    source: wallet?.publicKey,
  })
)
.add(
  updateAsUpdateAuthorityV2(umi, {
    mint: mint.publicKey,
    newUpdateAuthority: publicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECEIVER), // New authority
    ruleSet: publicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RULE_SET_ADDRESS),
  })
)
.sendAndConfirm(umi);

